# How to setup a domain in GKE ingress nginx

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

I have a cluster in GKE and it is working, everything seems to be working. If I forward the ports I am able to see that the containers are working.

I am not able to setup a domain I own from namecheap.

These are the steps I followed

1. In Namecheap I setup a custom dns for the domain

```
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
```

I used the letter `c` because the cluster is in a `c` zone (I am not sure if this is right)

2. Because I am trying to setup as secure website I installed nginx ingress controller

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```

and

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.46.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

3. I applied the `issuer.yml`

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-prod
 namespace: cert-manager
spec:
 acme:
   # The ACME server URL
   server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   # Email address used for ACME registration
   email: example@email.com
   # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-prod
   # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
   solvers:
   - http01:
       ingress:
         class:  nginx
```

4. I applied ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: staging
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - www.stagingmyappsrl.com
      - api.stagingmyappsrl.com
      secretName: stagingmyappsrl-tls
  rules:
  - host: wwwstaging.myappsrl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myappcatalogo-svc
          servicePort: 80

  - host: apistaging.stagingmyappsrl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myappnodeapi-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

It seems that everything is created and working if I check in GKE website, but when I try to access I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

I am not sure if I am missing an step or if I am setting up something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GKE should have created a cloud load balancer for your ingress service. Depending on your config, the LB can be internal or external. You can get your LB information by looking at the services:

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
```

Create a CNAME record in your DNS (namecheap) with the LB address and that should do it. Alternatively, if you have an IP address of the LB, create an A record in your DNS.

Cert-manager will create an ingress resource to resolve `HTTPS01` challenges. Make sure your ingresses are reachable over the Internet for the `HTTPS01` challenges to work. Alternatively, you could explore other solvers.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am able to see the ingress-nginx service with the command. I couldn't add a cname in namecheap, because it only allows to delegate the nameservers, but when I apply the config, a loadbalancer is created in gcp. Everything seems to be working (green) but for some reason it doesn't

Comment: I have never worked with namecheap but their documentation does suggest that they accept the CNAMEs (https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9252/2208/how-do-i-add-my-domain-to-google-sites/). However, if it doesn't then you will have to create a hosted DNS zone in GCP and then create the relevant CNAME records there. Your website should be accessible through the LB address if you pass in the correct host-header (curl -H "Host: <hostname>" <LB_Address>. You need to fix the DNS for everything to work correctly.

Comment: thank you for your help, as you pointed out I need to create the DNS in GCP, add a A record pointing to the generated LB and add a CNAME pointing to the A record.